# Flutter TypeAhead widget validation is not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, state

I have a form that has three types of widgets such that `DropDown`, `TextField`, and `TypeAhead`. I have imported a package named `flutter_typeahead` that is basically a dynamic DropDown mixed with TextField.(More info about `flutter_typeahead`: [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead), but there is no need to know `flutter_typeahead` widget to be able to understand and solve the problem.)

However, when I try to validate, if the `TypeAhead` widget is empty or null, then I throw an error to the user. Everything is ok up to now. But, when I fill the other instances of the form(`DropDown` and `TextFields`) and let the `TypeAhead` empty then the validation is not working. What I mean, If I fill the DropDowns and the TextFields and let the `TypeAhead` empty, then try to submit the form actually submits it. However, if I let the `TextField` empty or the `DropDown` as default the validation works fine.

To sum up, when all form widgets are empty, `TypeAhead` validation works, when only `TypeAhead` is empty it doesn't work.

### Form widget

```
Form formWidget(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          customTypeAhead(map['stajTuru'], _stajTuruController,
              _selectedStajTuru, 'Staj Türü'),  //Custom typeahead widget
          customTypeAhead(
              map['doktor'], _doktorController, _selectedDoktor, 'Doktor'), //Custom typeahead widget
          customDropDown(
              _valueOrtam, map['ortam'], hintTextOrtam, onChangedOrtam),
          customDropDown(
              _valueKapsam, map['kapsam'], hintTextKapsam, onChangedKapsam),
          customDropDown(_valueEtkilesim, map['etkilesim'], hintTextEtkilesim,
              onChangedEtkilesim),
          customDropDown(_valueCinsiyet, map['cinsiyet'], hintTextCinsiyet,
              onChangedCinsiyet),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          customTextField(
              1, "Kayıt No ", 10, _formData.setKayitNo, isEmpty, _kayit, 80),
          customTextField(
              1, "Hastanın Yaşı", 3, _formData.setYas, isNumeric, _yas, 80),
          customTextField(
              1, "Şikayet", 10, _formData.setSikayet, isEmpty, _sikayet, 80),
          customTextField(1, "Ayırıcı Tanı", 10, _formData.setAyiriciTani,
              isEmpty, _ayirici, 80),
          customTextField(5, "Kesin Tanı", 50, _formData.setKesinTani, isEmpty,
              _kesin, 130),
          customTextField(5, "Tedavi Yöntemi", 200, _formData.setTedaviYontemi,
              isEmpty, _tedavi, 130),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

### customTypeAhead

```
Widget customTypeAhead(List<String> listItems, TextEditingController controller,
     String? stajTuru,String labelText) {
  //check if the typed item is in the list
  List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    return List.of(listItems).where((item) {
      final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
      final itemLower = item.toLowerCase();
      return itemLower.contains(queryLower);
    }).toList();
  }

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(PADDING_VALUE),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          labelText,
          style: TEXT_STYLE,
        ),
        TypeAheadFormField<String?>(
          onSuggestionSelected: (String? val) =>controller.text = val!,
          itemBuilder: (context, String? suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(suggestion!),
            );
          },
          suggestionsCallback: getSuggestions,
          validator: (value) {  // This is my validation method
            bool isInTheList=false;
            for(var item in listItems){
              if(item==value) {
                isInTheList=true;
              }
            }
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty || isInTheList==false) {
              return 'Lütfen ${labelText.toLowerCase()} seçiniz';
            } else {
              print("null returned");
              return null;
            }
          },
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller: controller,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: TEXT_COLOR,
                    ),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: TEXT_COLOR,
                  )))),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

### Submit function

```
void formIlet() async {

    if (formArguments != null) {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        setFormArgumentState();
        bool res = await _mySqlHelper.insertData(formArguments!.formData);
        if (res) {
          _helper.update(formArguments!.formData);
          customSnackBar(context, 'Başarıyla gönderildi');
        } else {
          errorAlert(context);
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        setFormDataState();
        isLoading = true;
        bool res = await _mySqlHelper.insertData(_formData).then((val) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
            _formKey.currentState?.dispose();
          });
          return val;
        });
        if (res) {
          customSnackBar(context, 'Başarıyla gönderildi');
        } else {
          errorAlert(context);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I don't know why it happened, but using a ListView inside the Form is not a good idea. That's causing the problem. So, I changed the ListView with a Column and wrapped it with SingleChildScrollView the problem is solved.